# Why does Sentry not work with Log4j2 for me

Tags: java, log4j2, sentry

Hey I need help with sentry and log4j2.
Sentry works fine for me but when I want to use log4j2 no error is sent to sentry.

Otherwise sentry works fine without log4j2 can someone please help me please?

**This is my example Code**

```java
public class Test {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.error("test");
    }
}
```

normal and simple class

**This is my log4j2.xml**

```xml
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="warn" packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.core,io.sentry.log4j2">
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            </Console>
            <Sentry name="Sentry"
                    dsn="mydns"
                    minimumBreadcrumbLevel="DEBUG"
                    minimumEventLevel="WARN"
            />
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="warn">
                <AppenderRef ref="Sentry"/>
                <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

I got the log4j2.xml from the sentry documentation

**This is my pom**

```xml
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: On the surface it looks good. Can you enable Sentry debug by adding "sentry.properties" file with content debug=true in `src/main/resources`? You should see some helpful information in the stdout.

Comment: Hey @MaciejWalkowiak , thanks for your answer. I've done it and here is the result.            
```INFO: Initializing SDK with DSN: 'dns'
INFO: No outbox dir path is defined in options.
INFO: GlobalHubMode: 'false'
DEBUG: UncaughtExceptionHandlerIntegration enabled: true
DEBUG: UncaughtExceptionHandlerIntegration installed.
09:19:40.903 [main] ERROR me.ali.test.Test - test
INFO: Closing SentryClient.
DEBUG: Shutting down```

Comment: It looks good. Could you please post your project on github? I'll investigate what's not working

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak Sure here https://github.com/Ali1v/SentryTest , This is just a test project

Comment: There is an empty space at the beginning of ` log42.xml` file name. Rename the file and it will work as expected.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak Hey sorry  can you help me please.  With normal errors, I don't get any entries in Sentry. Why is that?

Comment: ```new StackOverflowError("Test").printStackTrace();```
I simulated an error but I don't get an error display in Sentry.

Comment: Please create an issue in https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java and attach a sample project. Either me or one of my colleagues will be able to help you there.